# Runnable update lag

Tags: android, runnable

My app is a basic clock and i use Runnable for updating the time and the Drawable, but it seems to have some lag in every minute its like 2 or 3 times, its freeze for aboute 2 sec.
This is my runnable code:

```
private Runnable updateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    updateTime();
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
```

Dose someone know what method to use, or how to fix this issue, its not fine for the clock to have missing seconds and drawable lag.

Comment: Please post the code for updateTime();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay is probably the amount of time it takes to process updateTime().  Try starting the new timer before you call updateTime().

private Runnable updateTimeTask = new Runnable() {

```
public void run() {

handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
updateTime();
}
```